# Automatically run tasks after Git Clone without using git hooks

Tags: git, bash, terminal

Is it possible to run automatically a .bash script after running `git clone ..repo..` inside the terminal? At first I wanted to run commands like `rm -rf .git` and `composer install` inside the post-checkout hook but this file can only be used locally. So are there other options to do this?

Comment: Where would you like it to run if not locally?

Comment: It must run locally but I don't wan't to create a file by hand for every user that's cloning a project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
mkdir ~/global_hooks
#create and edit the post-checkout inside
echo '#!/bin/bash' >> ~/global_hooks/post-checkout
echo 'rm -rf .git' >> ~/global_hooks/post-checkout
#...
chmod 755 ~/global_hooks/post-checkout
git config --global core.hooksPath ~/global_hooks/
```

Any new clone with a checkout (without `-n` or `--mirror` or `--bare`) will trigger `~/global_hooks/post-checkout` and `.git` will be removed. But this is not a good idea because you'll have to enable and disable the hook for different clones. Besides, every user needs to make the configuration, so it's a bit annoying.

What's worse, a git-checkout in a repository without disabling or overriding the global hook will remove its `.git`. So this is just for fun but not practical at all.

**Edit 2022-06-02:**

Some improvements to make it a bit more practical.

First, DO NOT run `git config --global core.hooksPath ~/global_hooks/`.

Second, update `~/global_hooks/post-checkout`

```
#!/bin/bash

enable=$(git config --get my.fun)
if [[ "${enable}" = yes ]];then
    echo Removing .git
    rm -rf .git
fi
```

Now it's possible to enable or disable the hook according to demand.

By default, a new clone or checkout does not invoke the hook, so the `.git` is safe.

When you really want to remove `.git` after it's cloned, add 2 options to `git`.

```
git -c core.hookspath=~/global_hooks/ -c my.fun=yes clone $repo_url -b $branch
```

`-c foo.bar=baz` is a temporary configuration value which works only for this git command. `my.fun` is a customized configuration word and you could replace it with other words you like.

Comment: `post-checkout` is run after all checkouts, and not just after a clone. Which is just something to be aware of, if you make a different version of this, where you only temporarily disable the hook when you run your clone of repos where you don't want `.git/` deleted, so you don't accidentally end up losing the `.git/` folder next time you run a checkout (e.g. checkout a different branch). (not an issue in the latter solution above, as you only include the hook specifically in the clone command)

Answer (score 2):

So, you want a repo configured such that when someone clones it, it immediately turns around and deletes everything but the work tree (making it no longer a clone of the repo)?  No, `git` does not have a way to do that.

If you just want to automate these steps because you have some frequent use case for it (maybe an unusual deployment mechanism?), then you can write a wrapper script to be run in lieu of the `git clone` command.

But if you literally want this triggered by the `git clone` command itself, that's not possible.  (It's also not useful; but that's none of my business.)