# Can VSCode or Git be configured to automatically run a script as soon a clone command finishes?

Tags: git, powershell, visual-studio-code, git-clone

Can VSCode or Git be configured to automatically run a script as soon a clone command finishes?  I want to run a PowerShell script that will automatically add a folder that contains scripts that I would then customize for working on the repo.  I can write the PowerShell script without issue.  I just don't know how, or even if, it's possible to make a script to run after the clone command finishes.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/2141492/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/10228065/7976758 , https://stackoverflow.com/q/45326925/7976758 Found in https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+clone+hook

Comment: use `git clone URL;myscript`